# How to run eslint --fix from npm script

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint, npm-scripts

I am trying to add lint-fix in my package.json.
My basic lint is `"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"`

I did try `"lint-fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"` but it is throwing my errors but not fixing them.

What do I have to change?

The error from NPM is:

```
217 problems (217 errors, 0 warnings)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run-script" "lint-fix"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm v3.8.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! quasar-app@0.0.1 lint-fix: eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue src
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! but it is caused by exit code 1 which is result of finding errors.
```

Comment: can you share error message/ stack trace?

Comment: @Gyandeep - list of errors,
 217 problems (217 errors, 0 warnings)


npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run-script" "lint-fix"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! quasar-app@0.0.1 lint-fix: `eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue src`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!

but it is caused by exit code 1 which is result of finding errors.

Answer (score 351, accepted):

You can run below command:

```
npm run lint -- --fix
```

Comment: Is this -- tricks works with every script ? Wondering for when I have a build error and its recommended to run --stacktrace...

Comment: Could you please explain what does it mean '--' here ?

Comment: @Arhacktector It is very common for programs to use `--` as an indicator to stop processing arguments from that point as command line options, for instance `rm -- *` would not trigger force removal even if there is a file named `-f`. So for this particular command line the `--` makes the npm command not interpret `--fix` as a command line option that it should interpret, but will instead will just pass it along "raw" to the program for the run sub-command. So the end result and objective is that the `--fix` argument is passed on to lint and not consumed by npm.

Comment: "npm run lint -- --fix" solved my issue of EsLint warnings & errors

Comment: This works for me to fix auto-fixable lint errors. Thank you :)

Answer (score 86):

You can add a new command in package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx ."
}
```

And then you can run it in terminal `npm run lint`.

Comment: what does --ext stand for?

Comment: --ext is the flag for extension

Comment: What's the period for after `jsx`?

Comment: I'd assume it'd mean for all files, but didn't we specify we only wanted to look at js and jsx files?

Comment: `.` at the end means "find files starting in the current directory" (recursively).

Answer (score 45):

To add a new separate script to auto-fix the linting issues for files with extensions `.js` and `.jsx`, you may add the add the script in your `package.json` as below:

`"lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx ."`

So after adding the above command the scripts section of your `package.json` may look like as below:

```
...
....
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx ."
},
....
...
```

**To run the newly added script to auto-fix the linting issues on the command line you should run the command like as below:**

`npm run lint:fix`

Comment: Im getting this warning , what would be my issue                                 ```Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .   ```

Comment: @Hitheshk use this https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2157#issuecomment-473680689

Answer (score 25):

Try

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix .
```

Comment: Welcome to SOF, please comment one-line answers, thanks

Comment: @PeymanMajidi One line answers are fine: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266954/one-line-answers

Comment: worked great. I ended up adding this to package.json: 

    "lint": " ./node_modules/.bin/eslint .",
    "lint:fix": " ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix ."

Answer (score 20):

### eslint auto-correct-command. It fixes all issues for me.

**To check the errors first:**

```
npx eslint .
```

**To fix the issues for all files (auto-correct options)**

```
npx eslint --fix .
```

Answer (score 14):

This is what I use:

```
npx eslint --fix .
```

It fixes all files.