# Eslint in React not correcting errors

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am working on a project that runs on node 10, "react": "^17.0.1".
"react-scripts": "^4.0.1",

On each project start is shows many warnings, for example usage o `==` instead of `===`, etc.

Here is part of the scripts, start original, the other 3 added by me trying to find a solution:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.dev --use-shell \"react-scripts start\"",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .js,.jsx",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "eslint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --fix"
},
```

I wanted to run eslint to automatically fix warnings. I tried the commands:

```
eslint "src/**/*.{js,jsx}" --fix
npm run eslint;
npm run lint
```

No matter what command I run I get such error message:
✖ 312 problems (3 errors, 309 warnings)

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! company@1.0.0 lint: `eslint src --ext .js,.jsx`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the company@1.0.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myname/.npm/_logs/2022-04-14T12_48_51_948Z-debug.log
```

Or:

✖ 312 problems (3 errors, 309 warnings)

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! company@1.0.0 lint: `eslint src --ext .js,.jsx "--fix"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the company@1.0.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myname/.npm/_logs/2022-04-14T12_57_18_764Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! company@1.0.0 lint:fix: `npm run lint -- --fix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the company@1.0.0 lint:fix script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myname/.npm/_logs/2022-04-14T12_57_18_794Z-debug.log
```

in the package.json there is this info:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
        "react-app"
    ]
},
```

No eslink packages installed in package.json - is should be using the react-scripts embedded eslint.

Does anybody have a clue how to make eslint fix a plenty of warnings nobody cared about?

**EDIT:**
Maybe this error appears after the list of warning, because in the middle there are also few errors such as:

*here path to the file*
10:41  error    React Hook "useState" is called in function "betaBanner" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter   react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

**EDIT 2:**
Yes, after I manually corrected the two errors it now writes in yellow `✖ 309 problems (0 errors, 309 warnings)` and the error at the end disappeared.

Comment: Can you try `npm run lint -- --fix`?

Comment: same error: `npm ERR! company@1.0.0 lint: `eslint src --ext .js,.jsx "--fix"``

Comment: are you using vscode ?

Comment: Do the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271230/how-to-run-eslint-fix-from-npm-script) help?

Comment: yes, VS Code...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes reinstalling the `node_modules` fixes such issues for me.

These are the steps I follow:

Clean `npm` cache : `npm cache clean --force`

Delete the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file.

Do a fresh package install : `npm install`

Start project : `npm start`

For VS Code, you can try adding these settings in your VS Code `settings.json`

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    "source.fixAll.tslint": true,
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
},
```

Comment: I added an EDIT at the bottom of the question, not sure if that error appears because eslint throws also few errors not only warnings... just wondering

Comment: I think you need to fix the React hooks warnings that you mentioned in the edit. Those are important for `React's` internal working. From the edit you added, I am assuming that you are using `useState` in a Class component, which is not allowed. You can only use hooks in functional components or other hooks.

Comment: Thank you yes. Now the error disappeared, but still the commands to fix warnings are not working. The same warnings keep reappearing

Comment: I've updated my answer and added some settings for VS Code which you can try. This might fix you issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this config to your .eslintrc configuration file

```
"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": [
       "warn",
        {
          "enableDangerousAutofixThisMayCauseInfiniteLoops": true
        }
      ]
```

Read more about the issue here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18235#issuecomment-898636301